# Using cell contents to set a range variable

Tags: string, vba, variables, set, range

I'm trying to run code on a range that changes through different iterations of a loop. Here is what I would like the code to run if the value in range("SearchBy") = ZeroCounts

```
Dim WorkRange As range
Set WorkRange = range("ZeroCounts")
```

Here is how I am attempting to solve this but I can't find a way that works without returning errors. Any ideas?

```
Dim dummy As String
dummy = """" & range("SearchBy").Value & """"

Dim WorkRange As range
WorkRange = Sheets("HungarianAlgorithm").range(dummy)

WorkRange.Select
```

Comment: Protip: when you ask a question about something that raises errors, it's usually a good idea to mention what the errors are.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Set` when assigning a value to an object-type variable

Try

```
Set WorkRange = Sheets("HungarianAlgorithm").Range(Range("SearchBy").Value)
```